# Fill in missing row with the date one month before the date in the preceding row

Tags: stata

I have data that looks like the following:

row,company_name,date_adj
1,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
2,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
3,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
4,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
5,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
6,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
7,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
8,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
9,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
10,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
11,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
12,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",31mar1990
13,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
14,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
15,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
16,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
17,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
18,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
19,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
20,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
21,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
22,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
23,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
24,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",31mar1991
25,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
26,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",
27,"PAPER PRODUCTS LTD.",

Each row represent a company and the date when some financial information was reported. Consider the date in row 12. I need to fill in row 11 under date_adj with the previous month and year (row 11 under date_adj should have 1990-02-28). I need to do this for every row under the variable date_adj. So the first eleven rows under date_adj should look like the following

row,date_adj
1,1989-04-31
2,1989-05-31
...
11,1990-02-28
12,1990-03-31

I'm using Stata to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what "previous month's date" is. For example, there's was no 4/31/1989 as far as I can remember. Here I just subtract 30 days.

```
/* Fake data */
clear
input id str10 str_date
1 "."    
1 "."  
1 "."    
1 "."    
1 "."    
1 "."    
1 "."    
1 "."    
1 "."    
1 "."
1 "."      
1 "1990-03-31"
1 "."    
1 "."  
1 "."    
1 "."    
1 "."    
1 "."    
1 "."    
1 "."    
1 "."    
1 "."   
1 "."
1 "1991-03-31"
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "1979-10-01"
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "."    
2 "1980-10-01"
end

/* Get a Stata daily date */
gen stata_date = date(str_date,"YMD")
format stata_date %td

/* Sort each company backwards */
bys id: gen order = _n
gsort id -order

/* Fill dates down and resort back */
bys id: replace stata_date = stata_date[_n-1]-30 if missing(stata_date)
sort id stata_date
```

Comment: Thanks! I have clarified my question. Your solution works. The only change is to use 31 instead of 30. This way for the case of 31march1990 the previous month won't be 01march1990 but will instead be 28feb1990.